# Having lists problems making a program for visualizing graph

Tags: python

I am a beginner at Python, and I am trying to make a program that can make a plot from a users input. The user uses an input to make x-coordinates and y-coordinates and add them into lists, and then visualize these in a plot. However, I get this error:
'list' object not callable
I am not sure where to put 'global' around the variables, so I have just tried it out all around. Any tips?
(this adds the x-values and y-values to a list)

```
def leggetil_verdier():
    global x_verdier 
    global y_verdier
    x_verdier= []
    y_verdier= []
    verdi_inn = input("Legg inn datapunktene dine (x,y), og avslutt med ferdig ")
    while verdi_inn !="ferdig":
        #verdi_inn = input("Legg inn datapunktene dine (x,y), og avslutt med ferdig ")
        if verdi_inn == "ferdig":
            break
        else:
            verdi_inn=verdi_inn.split(",")
            x_verdier.append(float(verdi_inn[0]))
            y_verdier.append(float(verdi_inn[1]))
            verdi_inn = input("Legg inn datapunktene dine (x,y), og avslutt med ferdig ")
    print(x_verdier)
    print(y_verdier)
    return x_verdier and y_verdier
```

(and this uses the lists)

```
def gjennomføring():
    spm_importere = input("Vil du lage en ny graf eller importere en allerede eksisterende graf? ny/importere ")
    if spm_importere =="importere":
        importere_graf()
        viseimport()
        handling_import = input("Vil du legge til datapunkter, endre på innstillinger (tittel og navn på akser), lagre grafen eller avslutte? datapunkter/innstillinger/lagre/avslutt")
        while endre!= "avslutte":
            if handling_import =="datapunkter":
                leggetil_verdier()
            elif handling_import =="innstilliger": 
                lagfunksjon()
            elif handling_funksjon =="lagre": 
                lagring_graf()
            endre = input("Vil du legge til datapunkter, endre på innstillinger (tittel og navn på akser), lagre grafen eller avslutte? datapunkter/innstillinger/lagre/avslutt ")
        
    elif spm_importere =="ny":
        endre = input("Vil du legge til datapunkter, endre på innstillinger (tittel og navn på akser), lagre grafen eller avslutte? datapunkter/innstillinger/lagre/avslutt ")
        while endre!= "avslutte":
            if endre =="datapunkter":
                leggetil_verdier()
                lagfunksjon()
            elif endre =="innstilliger": 
                lagfunksjon()
            else: 
                lagring_graf()
            endre = input("Vil du legge til datapunkter, endre på innstillinger (tittel og navn på akser), lagre grafen eller avslutte? datapunkter/innstillinger/lagre/avslutt ")
                   
gjennomføring()
```

Comment: If you want to return two elements from your function, you need `return x_verdier, y_verdier` and not `return x_verdier and y_verdier` which may try to do a Boolean comparison

Comment: Ah ok i changed it, thank you. It makes sense. But i still get the error but I think i have to do alot more haha

Comment: It's difficult to fully interpret your code, because I don't understand (what I think is) Norwegian... However, when you call your function to generate your data: `leggetil_verdier()` you need to assign your data to variables: `x, y = leggetil_verdier()` in order to use them for plotting and then, I'm guessing, pass them as arguments to `lagring_graf()`, e.g. `lagring_graf(x, y)` But it's hard to know without an understanding of the contents of `lagring_graf`

Comment: In general, I find it's always better to return and pass variables around, rather than use `global` too much, that way it's usually clearer what's happening, and where it's going wrong

Comment: I understand that it is hard to understand haha. I thought using arguments was optional? I could use them however I thought it would bring problems because "verdi_inn" is technically  local variable. "lagring_graf" is not included in the code above, however it makes the plot by making a title, and names on the x-axis and y-axis, and it also plots the lists above

Comment: I suspect that the error you're getting is inside `lagring_graf` and that you're doing this: `x_verdier()` or this: `y_verdier()`

Comment: Ah ok thank you,  I will look into it :)